# REST API - categories by store view code

Tags: magento2, category, rest-api, filter, store-view

I'm using Magento 2 and try to consume my categories by calling the REST API via /categories. 
How can I achieve it, to get the categories by an given store view code?

Do I have to extend the api by my own? I would expect, that this is an default requirement, but I haven't found any method, which would do this for me out of the box.

Or are there any search criterias for that?

Comment: Please specify magento version

Comment: @AmitBera does the behavior version depedent?  will the accepted answer work for Magento2.3?

Comment: API point does not version depend, But it related php interface/class might be change on version change for backward compatibility  .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is quite simple:

http://localhost/rest/{store code}/V1/categories

Just replace the **{store code}** with yours.

For example English would be:

http://localhost/rest/en/V1/categories

Comment: work perfect :)

Comment: @benjamin How can this be achieved on a custom API ./rest/en/V1/vendor/module/id/2 ? I cannot read store store code only if I add a parameter like this: /rest/en/V1/vendor/module/id/2?storeCode=en